# No OS Found while trying to Install?

Tags: windows-8

I currently have a problem, I have the USB Version of Ubuntu..And if I try to install it, it says I have no OS installed! And I don't know how to install it without erasing Windows 8! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there any something else option present,please select it.

Comment: No there isn't, There's a Erase Disk option and a Something Else option.

Comment: i believe he means click "SOMETHING ELSE" option

Answer (score 0):

select `Something Else` option,it will take you to select which partition you are going to install Ubuntu.Select that partition and format it to `ext4` filesystem and install ubuntu on it.

Then don't forget to create swap partition and its size must be double the RAM size.